# Почему компилятор выдает InvalidPathExeption?

Tags: java, компиляция, компилятор

При старте программы нужно загрузить текстовый файл. Код выполняется в блоке `static` и должен подгружать список. Код реализован следующим образом:

```java
static {
        try {
            String domains = GUI.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResource("Domains.txt").getPath();
            File file = new File(domains);
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
            DOMAINS = text.split("\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            showError("File Domains.txt don't find!");
            }       
        }
```

В среде разработки всё работает. А при компиляции .jar файла выдаёт ошибку ***InvalidPathExeption: Illegal char <:>***

Как правильно прикрепить текстовый файл к проекту?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что ошибку вам выдаёт компилятор?

Comment: Что же до причины ошибки - поищите ваш Domains.txt на диске. Когда не найдёте его - задумайтесь, каким образом вы можете прочитать через Files.readAllBytes отсутствующий файл

Comment: @PavelMayorov потому что ошибка возникает при запуске .jar файла через командную строку. Файл лежит в директории  **src** и на всякий случай в папке **bin**

Comment: Кстати, как вы думаете, зачем придумали метод [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: И да, если ошибка возникает при **запуске**, почему вы говорите про **компилятор**?

Comment: @PavelMayorov почему вы задаёте вопросы, а не отвечаете на мой вопрос?

Comment: @PavelMayorov *"поищите ваш Domains.txt на диске"* - как можно искать файл с ошибкой в адресе Illegal char? - `file.toPath()` вызывает исключение.  А как это (дёшево) исправить - я пока что не знаю.

Comment: Я пытаюсь навести вас на решение вашего вопроса. Что же до того как искать - любым файловым менеджером.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я понимаю, что можно получить адрес и через URL... Но, в таком случае я не могу прочитать файл в 1 строку кода.

Comment: Хм, а что делает метод  readAllBytes​() у InputStream?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Читает байты. Спасибо!) С `getResourceAsStream()` всё работает. Файл загрузился.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы можете первым опробовать демоверсию программы. [Readme](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13UUZgjD4cN1gbqHg1oMBcoFZEexZgxbN/view?usp=sharing) [.jar файл](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18fDKh0vKWvOoI3gBouy5UpbE0jwznOyt/view?usp=sharing)